# How do I make s SIMPLE terminal game with real-time input on Linux?

Tags: input

I am looking a bit of simple code that will take whatever data comes from the keyboard at a given moment and let me check it for certain button presses. It doesn't matter what language it is in.

I am looking for a console solution, no GUI.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for the [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) library (you may also find an implementation as "ncurses", which is probably already installed on your system). This library powers most of the "full-screen" console programs that you might see on Linux.